# Trying to send multiple lists of Strings in post request using webClient in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient

- I am trying to send 3 different lists via webClient but I am getting a validation exception from API which expects interface java.util.List.

This is how controller endpoint looks like:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/uploadFiles", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  public ResponseDto<List<UploadFileDto>> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("A") List<String> a, 
                                                      @RequestParam("B") List<Short> b, 
                                                      @RequestParam("C") List<MultipartFile> c)
```

And this is how i am trying to create a request:

```
private void callUploadFileEndpoint() throws IOException{
        var uploadFileRequest = filesGenerator.generateRequest();

        List<byte[]> byteArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for(MultipartFile multipartFile : uploadFileRequest.getC()) {
            var bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
            byteArray.add(bytes);
        }
        
        MultipartBodyBuilder multipartBodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        multipartBodyBuilder.part("A", uploadFileRequest.getA());
        multipartBodyBuilder.part("B", uploadFileRequest.getB());
        multipartBodyBuilder.part("C", byteArray);
        
        try {
            Tuple2<Long, String> responseTuple = webClient.post().uri("/v1/uploadFiles")
                    .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(bearerAuth))
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartBodyBuilder.build()))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .elapsed()
                    .block();
            System.out.printf("Response time: %d ms%n", responseTuple.getT1());
        } catch (WebClientResponseException exception) {
            System.err.println(exception.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

and UploadFileRequestClass :

```
@Data
@Builder
public class UploadFileRequest {
    List<String> a;
    List<Short> b;
    List<MultipartFile> c;
}
```

Any idea how to build a proper body with multiple lists for the request? Is it even possible to build such complex request with webClient? Maybe I should use different one?

Answer (score 0):

After some time I've realised that I wrongly understood the concept of the body as whole. I wanted to pass 3 different lists in a single body. Passing generic lists as queryParam string and multipart list as body resolved my issue.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < uploadFileRequest.getC().size(); i++) {
   multipartBodyBuilder.part("C", uploadFileRequest.getC().get(i).getResource());
}

try {
    Tuple2<Long, String> responseTuple = webClient.post().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path("/v1/uploadFiles")
            .queryParam("A", aSb.toString())
            .queryParam("B", bSb.toString())
            .build())
        .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(bearerAuth))
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)                
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartBodyBuilder.build()))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .elapsed()
        .block();
    System.out.printf("Response time: %d ms%n", responseTuple.getT1());
    System.out.println(responseTuple.getT2());
} catch (WebClientResponseException exception) {
    System.err.println(exception.getResponseBodyAsString());
    throw exception;
}
```